# $\mathbb{R}^3$ isn't isomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{C}$

Tags: ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

How to show the two rings $\mathbb{R}^3 = \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{C}$ aren't ring isomorphic to each other?

My attempt:

Since $\mathbb{R}^2$ isn't an Integral Domain as $(1,0).(0,1) = (0,0)$, It's not a field. But $\mathbb{C}$ is a field. So $\mathbb{R}^2$ isn't isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

Therefore, $\mathbb{R}^3$ isn't Ring Isomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{C}$

Is the logic okay? If not, then could you tell me how to show this one.

Comment: Count idempotents in both rings: $8$ vs. $4$.

Comment: Two instructive points about this problem. 1) Want to prove two things are not isomorphic to each other? Find an algebraic invariant which distinguishes them. For D_S, it's the number of $n$th roots of unity (for any $n$, you get to choose); for rschwieb it's the number of idempotents; for my answer, it's the number of orthogonal pairs (I don't know if a better name for this exists). 2) All three methods ultimately (when written in full detail) require the use of the projection maps to reduce the problem to counting the same things about the factors, which is a lesson about direct products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, the existing solutions are a bit more complicated than the one that I would use.

$\mathbb R^3$ has 8 idempotents and $\mathbb R\times \mathbb C$ only has four.  An idempotent is an element $e$ such that $e^2=e$.  Naturally an isomorphism must match up idempotents to idempotents.

Comment: This proof is very slick, and is just as general as mine because an integral domain must have exactly 2 idempotents.

Answer (score 5):

It is not generally true for rings that $A \times B \cong A \times C$ implies $B \cong C$, so your proof does not work as stated.

Try looking at roots of unity.  In $\mathbb C$ there is the unit circle, which contains many, many elements $z$ with the property that $z^n = 1$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$.  Therefore in the ring $R = \mathbb R \times \mathbb C$, the same is true.

What are the roots of unity in $S = \mathbb R^3$?

Comment: What's a counterexample for $A\times B \cong A\times C \implies B\cong C$?

Comment: $A = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \cdots$,

$B = \mathbb R$,

$C = \mathbb R^2$

Comment: Indeed,  $x^3=1$ has one solution in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ but three solutions in $\mathbb R \times \mathbb C$.

Answer (score 2):

As D_S stated in their answer, your proof does not work as stated because for rings, $R_{0}\times R_{1}\cong R_{0}\times R_{2}$ does not imply that $R_{1}\cong R_{2}.$ What follows is a very direct line of argument. I encourage you to read the next paragraph, think about how you would prove it, and only then reveal the spoilers.

In $\mathbb{R}^{3},$ there exist three distinct non-zero elements $a_{1}=(1,0,0),$ $a_{2}=(0,1,0)$ and $a_{3}=(0,0,1)$ such that the product of any two of them is zero: $a_{1}a_{2}=a_{2}a_{3}=a_{3}a_{1}=(0,0,0).$ No such triple of elements exists in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{C},$ and therefore the two rings cannot be isomorphic to each other.

> To prove this, suppose, for a contradiction, that $A_{1},A_{2},A_{3}\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{C}$ are distinct, non-zero, and satisfy the conditions $A_{1}A_{2}=A_{2}A_{3}=A_{3}A_{1}=(0,0).$ Let $\pi_{1}\colon \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\pi_{2}\colon \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ denote the coordinate functions (so for example, $\pi_{2}(1,2+3i)=2+3i$). Then for $j=1,2,$ $$\pi_{j}(A_{1})\pi_{j}(A_{2})=\pi_{j}(A_{2})\pi_{j}(A_{3})=\pi_{j}(A_{3})\pi_{j}(A_{1})=0.$$ Without loss of generality, we may assume that $\pi_{1}(A_{1})=0$ (otherwise, just relabel things). Since $A_{1}$ is non-zero, we must now have $\pi_{2}(A_{1})\neq0,$ and therefore $\pi_{2}(A_{2})=\pi_{2}(A_{3})=0.$ Now it follows that $\pi_{1}(A_{2})\neq0$ and $\pi_{1}(A_{3})\neq0$ since $A_{2}$ and $A_{3}$ are non-zero. But this means that $\pi_{1}(A_{2})\pi_{1}(A_{3})\neq0$ also, a contradiction.

> The key fact that makes this argument work is that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are both integral domains (so, in your attempt, you were right to pick up on the distinguishing feature that $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is not an integral domain, whereas $\mathbb{C}$ is). This is what allowed us to deduce that $\pi_{2}(A_{2})=\pi_{2}(A_{3})=0.$ Without this, the argument falls apart. I encourage you to think about how this argument is essentially a form of the pigeonhole principle in action.